# XSL recursion axis fault?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml sitemap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="NewSiteMap.xsl"?>
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode
    url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=1"
    title="Home"
    description="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
    <siteMapNode
      url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=2"
      title="Profile"
      description="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" />
    <siteMapNode
      url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=3"
      title="People"
      description="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" />
    <siteMapNode
      url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=5"
      title="New Page"
      description="DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

And the following xsl file to do recursion and output to ul:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:template match="siteMap">
<!--  
<xsl:variable name='siteMapNode'>
 <xsl:value-of select='siteMap/siteMapNode'/>
</xsl:variable> 
-->
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="xSiteMap.css" type="text/css" />  
  </head>

  <body>
       <h2>SiteMap:</h2>
   <ul>
    <!-- Check for empty sitemap -->
    <xsl:if test='siteMapNode'>
     <xsl:call-template name='BuildNavList'>
      <xsl:with-param name='siteMapNode' select='siteMapNode'/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>     
      </ul>
  </body>

</html> 

</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name='BuildNavList'>
 <xsl:param name='siteMapNode'/>
 <li> 
  <a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="$siteMapNode/@url"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="$siteMapNode/@description"/>       
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="$siteMapNode/@title"/>
  </a> 
    <!-- test for node-children, if true then recursion -->
  <xsl:if test='$siteMapNode/node()'>
   <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$siteMapNode/node()">
       <xsl:call-template name='BuildNavList'>
      <xsl:with-param name='siteMapNode' select='$siteMapNode/node()'/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>  
   </ul>
  </xsl:if> 
 </li> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But there seems to be an error in my recursion call (propably an axis error in my for-each statement)! What goes wrong here?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that uses XSLT patern-matching to the maximum and has no conditionals inside any template. :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gaby's answer, you might want to know that using call-template and passing one parameter, a node, is just a roundabout way of saying apply-templates to that node (without template matching). Apply-templates is the normal XSLT way of doing what you're doing, and it's less verbose.

So your initial call-template

```
<xsl:if test='siteMapNode'>
 <xsl:call-template name='BuildNavList'>
  <xsl:with-param name='siteMapNode' select='siteMapNode'/>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

can become

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select='siteMapNode'/>
```

which will apply to children of the context node named siteMapNode.

Then your recursive template becomes

```
<xsl:template match="siteMapNode">
 <li> 
  <a href="{@url}" title="{@description}">
   <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
  </a> 
    <!-- test for siteMapNode element children, if true then recur -->
  <xsl:if test='siteMapNode'>
   <ul>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode" />
   </ul>
  </xsl:if> 
 </li> 
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that we eliminated a lot of references to the $siteMapNode parameter because that's now the context node. Notice also the Attribute Value Templates used for `<a href=""` and `title="">`. Much more succinct and readable!

XSLT really is more convenient when you understand and use it the way it was designed!

Comment: +1 For the XSLT answer: apply templates and pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

In the `BuildNavList` template change the inner template call to

```
<xsl:for-each select="$siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
   <xsl:call-template name='BuildNavList'>
  <xsl:with-param name='siteMapNode' select='.'/>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the important thing is to use the `.` in the `xsl:with-param` because you are already inside the loop of the nodes...

the seconds issue is the `for-each select`. In this case i use the `/siteMapNode` to ignore the whitespace between the elements because the `node()` alternative takes whitespace into account as text nodes and gets messed up.

If you have to use the `nodes()` version (*at the `for-each select`*) then you can add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` on the top of your xslt so that it will remove them ..

Comment: God damn, thanks alot Gaby. Works like a charm! I need to look into those axis statements! Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

Following the good answers by @LarsH and @Gaby, let me show my preferred way of solving this problem.

In XSLT any conditional (`<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`) is an indication that the full power of XSLT pattern matching has not been used.

Instead of such conditionals, try to use as much as possible pattern-matching in the `match` attribute of `<xsl:template>`.

**My solution is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="xSiteMap.css" type="text/css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <h2>SiteMap:</h2>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode"/>
      </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[1]">
  <ul>
   <xsl:call-template name="buildNav"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::siteMapNode"
        mode="inList"/>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="siteMapNode" name="buildNav">
  <li>
    <a href="{@url}" title="{@description}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode"/>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="siteMapNode" mode="inList">
  <xsl:call-template name="buildNav"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="siteMapNode[position() > 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode
    url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=1"
    title="Home"
    description="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">

        <siteMapNode
         url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=2"
         title="Profile"
         description="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" />

        <siteMapNode
      url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=3"
      title="People"
      description="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" />

        <siteMapNode
      url="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=5"
      title="New Page"
      description="DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" /></siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

**the wanted, correct answer is produced**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="xSiteMap.css" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>SiteMap:</h2>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=1" title="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">Home</a><ul>
               <li><a href="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=2" title="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB">Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=3" title="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC">People</a></li>
               <li><a href="~/UsingMasterTemplate.aspx?id=5" title="DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD">New Page</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Do note**: how the `<xsl:if>` s disappeared "magically".